# Level-sensitive SR Latch behavior

Tags: circuit

I am looking into the difference between a regular SR latch and a level sensitive SR Latch.

[Level - sensitive SR Latch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNXSF.png)

I am aware that what we want to avoid in an SR latch is the configuration (1,1) because it can cause an oscillation and when it finally settles on a 0 or 1 we can't be certain which one due to the oscillation. Thus, we use a level sensitive SR latch. But can someone elaborate on the behavior of this level-sensitive SR latch. Because if S,R, and C(usually a clock) are all 1, it seems to me that we can still end up with the same (1,1) configuration that we are trying to avoid.

I have found this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21887/difference-between-latch-and-flip-flop) and it talks about the difference between a latch and a flip-flop. But just to re-iterate, my main question is if clk = 1 and if S =1, R =1, then can't we still end up in a loop of oscillations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SR flipflop is designed so that C is only 1 when S and R are stable. It is designed very carefully as to prevent C from being 1 when S=R=1. However, this is not apparent at all given the basic diagram of the flip flop.

An improvement to this is the D flipflop. It inverts one of the signals from the SR flipflop. This ensures that S and R are never the same. This can be seen in the image below. 
[image]